# how to check if i have At least one file *.bak in my folder?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to check if i have At least one file `*.bak` in my folder ?

Comment: This topic will probably win most answers in 10 seconds :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all files in a particular directory using [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx). The second parameter is a pattern to search for (which includes wildcards). Something like this should do it:

```
var hasBak = Directory.GetFiles(yourdir, "*.bak").Length > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Directory.GetFiles` is correct, but not the best solution if you are using C# 4.0, because we have:

```
bool exist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\mydir", "*.bak").Any();
```

`Directory.GetFiles` returns all those matched files, and you can check the `Length` property. But when we invoke `Any` to `Directory.EnumerateFiles`, essentially we get its enumerator and `MoveNext`, the method returns as soon as we found any item in it(in this way we always don't need to loop through all the files). I checked their implementation, and test with:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Windows", "*.log").Any();
```

`GetFiles` costs 4x time than `EnumerateFiles`(run them 10000 times, measuring by `StopWatch`).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `Directory.GetFiles(directory. "*.bak")` to get the list of bak files, and then just check whether the length is 0 or not.

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.bak").Length == 0)
{
    // Complain to the user or whatever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool IsAtleastOneFilePresent()
{ 
   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.bak");
   if(filePaths.Length > 0)  return true; else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\SomeDirectory\", "*.bak");
```

and ensure that files.Length > 0

Answer (score 1):

Use Directory.GetFiles

```
Directory.GetFiles([dir], "*.bak")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx